# Http Authentication , Cancel Loop

Tags: php, http, authentication, basic-authentication

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    }
?>
```

I am using this code which simply ask for username and password for authentication , but the question is when user click on cancel button it is supposed to give authentication prompt again and again until correct username and password is not provided.

Comment: hitting esc at the http basic prompt tends to cancel the request that caused the prompt, meaning there's nothing you can do to trigger something in the client, because it's disconnected from you now.

Comment: I understand Marc but my concern is if esc is pressed or cancel is hit in that case also i want prompt to reappear which i have seen somewhere and it's possible but i don't know how that guy achieved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple fix can be implemented assuming your clients all have JavaScript.

Instead of `echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';`:

```
echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';
```

Comment: Can you provide me small code to achieve this. I have tried this it gives page can not redirect to itself

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 
exit();
```

would work in php